# Visual Studio Code unable to compile cpp and Cuda (cu) files together

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cuda

I have c++ program with multiple cpp files in VS code. Recently I learned some CUDA programming and tried to add a cuda functionality to this program. However, the nvcc compiler fails. If I try renaming the cu file to cpp I get an error:

```
expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
    cuda_hello<<<1, 1>>>();
```

I understand this is because the nvcc then ignores that the file has cuda codes. So is there a way I can compile the cpp and cu files separately and then combine them or some other solution in VS code itself, maybe by changing the tasks.json file.

Comment: You probably want to use CMake with VSCode for this.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, yes they open. However these are compiled using a makefile. I am not very skilled in making a Makefile and that is why I was wondering if I could find a VS code based solution

Comment: @drescherjm: could you elaborate on this? Maybe a link to a tutorial or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. Make sure that your nvcc is up to date (v 11) and update the tasks.json arguments as follows:

```
"args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "*.cu",
                "*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
```

Make sure CUDA codes are present in *.cu formats.